# Python read json from url

Tags: python, json

With Python 3, I want to read a JSON from url.
This is what I got:

```
import json
import urllib.request
url_address = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url_address) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read())
print(data)
```

However, it gives: `HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`

Comment: to me even browser gave `{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}`

Comment: The url is of course an example, it should show:  `{"errors":[{"message":"The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.","code":64}]}`

Comment: To read json from url use requests that is best suited also convert the url address to ip address and add arguments to it. For further description read docs at (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ )

Comment: Could this be my proxy server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

twitter is returning 400 code(bad request) so exception is firing.
you can use try...except in your code sample and read exception body to get response json {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

```py
import json
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError


try:

    url_address ='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url_address) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read())
        print(data)

except HTTPError as ex:
    print(ex.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

To me below code is working- in Python 2.7

```
import json
from urllib import urlopen
url_address = ['https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json']
for i in url_address:
    resp = urlopen(i)
    data = json.loads(resp.read())
print(data)
```

Output-

```
{u'errors': [{u'message': u'Bad Authentication data.', u'code': 215}]}
```

If you use `requests` module-

```
import requests
url_address = ['https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json']
for i in url_address:
    resp = requests.get(i).json()
    print resp
```

Output-

```
{u'errors': [{u'message': u'Bad Authentication data.', u'code': 215}]}
```

Comment: With Python 3 use `urllib.request.urlopen`. Still this doesnt work for me. Also another example url `https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos`, I get the error: `the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'`

Comment: `data = json.loads(resp.read().decode())` did the job! Can you explain briefly the reason?

Comment: It is just explicitly saying to decode- but it supposed to occur.

Comment: Why are you iterating over a list with one element?

Comment: I just gave a sense in case of multiple element.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `aiohttp`, it's asynchronous. Last time I checked, `urllib` was blocking. This means that it will prevent other parts of the script from running while it itself is running. Here's an example for `aiohttp`:

```
import aiohttp
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
async with session.get('https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos') as resp:

    print(await resp.json())
```